# $\cap$-stable sets

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, notation

I dont know if it the right place to ask this type of question:

I am reading a book (De Gruyter Studies in Mathematics) Heinz Bauer, Robert B. Bruckel-Probability Theory. 23-Walter de Gruyter & Co (1996). Here I came up with a notation whose description I can't find in the book.

The Notation : $\cap$-stable sets.

Can someone explain me the notation?

Comment: See [Stable under Intersection](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Stable_under_Intersection).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks. Is it true for only finite intersection?